# 3rd party products that generate SAML requests to the IdP on behalf of the SP

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I'm investigating the feasibility of SP-initiated SSO in the context of our solution whereby a 3rd party product would like to launch our product so that the user does not need to authenticate again.

The jist of the workflow is:

1. user of 3rd party product (client) initiates a request to our
   product (the SP)
2. SP initiates a SAML request to the IdP
3. IdP responds with the SAML assertion

Unfortunately, our product cannot currently send SAML requests to an IdP (i.e. we cannot do step 2).

Are there any 3rd party products out there that could "act" as an SP (listen for requests from 3rd party and send a SAML request to the IdP) on behalf our the real SP, in effect, perform Step 2 for us?

Comment: Are you looking for a standalone product or a library to call into from your application?

If you're after a library, what platform/language does your application use?

Comment: I'm looking for a product, but if a library does the job then I could consider. We use Java and Windows. Was looking at Okta as a product, but haven't yet reached a conclusion around its suitability.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few Java libraries that you can use. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207402/web-sso-using-java-and-saml-2-0) for a similar question to yours. In addition to the helpful answers provided there, here's [another well-maintained open source Java library](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml) from OneLogin that you can look at. It's well-maintained and comes from a major competitor in the space.